# check constraint with date

Tags: sql

i want to apply check constraint with date  for eg delivery date is greate than order date how to apply this constraint any can help me out

```
alter table sales_order modify dely_date check (dely_date>order_Date);
```

its show error

Comment: which database system  are you using, and what  is the exact error message (as text)

Answer (score 1):

This is how to add `CHECK` `constraint` in an existing column :

```
alter table sales_order ADD CONSTRAINT CHK_dates check (dely_date>order_Date);
```